# CMake Visual Studio 'Debug' Folder

Tags: visual-studio, cmake

Visual Studio insists that it has to create executables in bin/Debug/ instead of just bin/, when using CMake.
Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, but is not really pretty...

You will need to update the [RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake-2-8-docs.html#prop_tgt%3aRUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY), [LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake-2-8-docs.html#prop_tgt%3aLIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY) and [ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake-2-8-docs.html#prop_tgt%3aARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY) properties on **ALL** your targets. And you will need to do this for every configuration (Debug, RelWithDebInfo, etc.)

The easiest way is to do this "globally" with their CMAKE_... equivalents. E.g. check the following sample which sets bin/ and lib/ as the "global" binary/library output-directories:

```
# First for the generic no-config case (e.g. with mingw)
set( CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin )
set( CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib )
set( CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib )
# Second, for multi-config builds (e.g. msvc)
foreach( OUTPUTCONFIG ${CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES} )
    string( TOUPPER ${OUTPUTCONFIG} OUTPUTCONFIG )
    set( CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_${OUTPUTCONFIG} ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin )
    set( CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_${OUTPUTCONFIG} ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib )
    set( CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_${OUTPUTCONFIG} ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib )
endforeach( OUTPUTCONFIG CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES )
```

Alternatively, you can try to run through all the available targets and modify its properties afterwards...

Note that this does not set the location of your .pdb files. I still have not found a satisfying way to put all the relevant .pdb files in the bin/ directory.

Comment: Is there a way at all, even if not satisfying, to put the pdb files in the bin/ directory?

Comment: No, not really, except doing it yourself: I have not yet done it, but am thinking about running a post-build script which "copies" *.pdb (perhaps those from a list of targets) to the bin directory... But it will not really be extensible.

Comment: Well, maybe I'll try and do that. I'll test this later, hopefully it'll work.